# How to file bitcoin income to the IRS

Tags: coinbase.com, legal, taxes, usa

I want to check if there is any specific tips how to properly file income from speculation with BTC to the IRS.

Also is there any specific report from the Coinbase available?

Comment: According to CoinDesk, IRS finally announced guidance [What the IRS Bitcoin Tax Guidelines Mean For You](http://www.coindesk.com/irs-bitcoin-tax-guidelines-mean/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IRS has not ruled on this yet.  So I plan to treat Bitcoins as an asset for now.  This means keeping track of your cost basis (purchase price + fees) and deducting this from your net sell (sell price - fees) to determine the capital gain or loss.  Since you have no control over the specific coins you sell, you should probably use the FIFO (first-in first-out) accounting method.

Here are a some links to discussions on this subject:

[Taxes on Bitcoin Transactions](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=104149.0)

[Reporting bitcoin mining earnings to IRS](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=156418.0)

Comment: How does this compare for coins that are mined? The purchase price is zero obviously but as a miner you do have expenses, ie power and cost of the computers/GPU/asics etc.  Can those costs be deducted from the price you sold at?

Comment: I would think you could deduct equipment and electricity used for mining as an investment expense.  But this is really an unknown area and there is no telling how the IRS is going to rule on this.  If your mining nets you a significant amount of money, then you really need to consult an accountant.

Answer (score 4):

The IRS just issued a preliminary ruling on this and it will be treated as property.  The Q&A portion is particularly useful.

SECTION 4. FREQUENTLY ASKED QUESTIONS

Q-1: How is virtual currency treated for federal tax purposes?

A-1: For federal tax purposes, virtual currency is treated as property. General tax principles applicable to property transactions apply to transactions using virtual currency.

Q-2: Is virtual currency treated as currency for purposes of determining whether a transaction results in foreign currency gain or loss under U.S. federal tax laws?

A-2: No. Under currently applicable law, virtual currency is not treated as currency that could generate foreign currency gain or loss for U.S. federal tax purposes.

Q-3: Must a taxpayer who receives virtual currency as payment for goods or services include in computing gross income the fair market value of the virtual currency?

A-3: Yes. A taxpayer who receives virtual currency as payment for goods or services must, in computing gross income, include the fair market value of the virtual currency, measured in U.S. dollars, as of the date that the virtual currency was received. See Publication 525, Taxable and Nontaxable Income, for more information on miscellaneous income from exchanges involving property or services.

Q-4: What is the basis of virtual currency received as payment for goods or services in Q&A-3?

A-4: The basis of virtual currency that a taxpayer receives as payment for goods or services in Q&A-3 is the fair market value of the virtual currency in U.S. dollars as of the date of receipt. See Publication 551, Basis of Assets, for more information on the computation of basis when property is received for goods or services.

Q-5: How is the fair market value of virtual currency determined?

A-5: For U.S. tax purposes, transactions using virtual currency must be reported in U.S. dollars. Therefore, taxpayers will be required to determine the fair market value of virtual currency in U.S. dollars as of the date of payment or receipt. If a virtual currency is listed on an exchange and the exchange rate is established by market supply and demand, the fair market value of the virtual currency is determined by converting the virtual currency into U.S. dollars (or into another real currency which in turn can be converted into U.S. dollars) at the exchange rate, in a reasonable manner that is consistently applied.

Q-6: Does a taxpayer have gain or loss upon an exchange of virtual currency for other property?

A-6: Yes. If the fair market value of property received in exchange for virtual currency exceeds the taxpayer's adjusted basis of the virtual currency, the taxpayer has taxable gain. The taxpayer has a loss if the fair market value of the property received is less than the adjusted basis of the virtual currency. See Publication 544, Sales and Other Dispositions of Assets, for information about the tax treatment of sales and exchanges, such as whether a loss is deductible.

Q-7: What type of gain or loss does a taxpayer realize on the sale or exchange of virtual currency?

A-7: The character of the gain or loss generally depends on whether the virtual currency is a capital asset in the hands of the taxpayer. A taxpayer generally realizes capital gain or loss on the sale or exchange of virtual currency that is a capital asset in the hands of the taxpayer. For example, stocks, bonds, and other investment property are generally capital assets. A taxpayer generally realizes ordinary gain or loss on the sale or exchange of virtual currency that is not a capital asset in the hands of the taxpayer. Inventory and other property held mainly for sale to customers in a trade or business are examples of property that is not a capital asset. See Publication 544 for more information about capital assets and the character of gain or loss.

Q-8: Does a taxpayer who "mines" virtual currency (for example, uses computer resources to validate Bitcoin transactions and maintain the public Bitcoin transaction ledger) realize gross income upon receipt of the virtual currency resulting from those activities?

A-8: Yes, when a taxpayer successfully "mines" virtual currency, the fair market value of the virtual currency as of the date of receipt is includible in gross income. See Publication 525, Taxable and Nontaxable Income, for more information on taxable income.

Q-9: Is an individual who "mines" virtual currency as a trade or business subject to self-employment tax on the income derived from those activities?

A-9: If a taxpayer's "mining" of virtual currency constitutes a trade or business, and the "mining" activity is not undertaken by the taxpayer as an employee, the net earnings from self-employment (generally, gross income derived from carrying on a trade or business less allowable deductions) resulting from those activities constitute self-employment income and are subject to the self-employment tax. See Chapter 10 of Publication 334, Tax Guide for Small Business, for more information on self-employment tax and Publication 535, Business Expenses, for more information on determining whether expenses are from a business activity carried on to make a profit.

Q-10: Does virtual currency received by an independent contractor for performing services constitute self‑employment income?

A-10: Yes. Generally, self‑employment income includes all gross income derived by an individual from any trade or business carried on by the individual as other than an employee. Consequently, the fair market value of virtual currency received for services performed as an independent contractor, measured in U.S. dollars as of the date of receipt, constitutes self‑employment income and is subject to the self-employment tax. See FS-2007-18, April 2007, Business or Hobby? Answer Has Implications for Deductions, for information on determining whether an activity is a business or a hobby.

Q-11: Does virtual currency paid by an employer as remuneration for services constitute wages for employment tax purposes?

A-11: Yes. Generally, the medium in which remuneration for services is paid is immaterial to the determination of whether the remuneration constitutes wages for employment tax purposes. Consequently, the fair market value of virtual currency paid as wages is subject to federal income tax withholding, Federal Insurance Contributions Act (FICA) tax, and Federal Unemployment Tax Act (FUTA) tax and must be reported on Form W-2, Wage and Tax Statement. See Publication 15 (Circular E), Employer's Tax Guide, for information on the withholding, depositing, reporting, and paying of employment taxes.

Q-12: Is a payment made using virtual currency subject to information reporting?

A-12: A payment made using virtual currency is subject to information reporting to the same extent as any other payment made in property. For example, a person who in the course of a trade or business makes a payment of fixed and determinable income using virtual currency with a value of $600 or more to a U.S. non-exempt recipient in a taxable year is required to report the payment to the IRS and to the payee. Examples of payments of fixed and determinable income include rent, salaries, wages, premiums, annuities, and compensation.

Q-13: Is a person who in the course of a trade or business makes a payment using virtual currency worth $600 or more to an independent contractor for performing services required to file an information return with the IRS?

A-13: Generally, a person who in the course of a trade or business makes a payment of $600 or more in a taxable year to an independent contractor for the performance of services is required to report that payment to the IRS and to the payee on Form 1099-MISC, Miscellaneous Income. Payments of virtual currency required to be reported on Form 1099-MISC should be reported using the fair market value of the virtual currency in U.S. dollars as of the date of payment. The payment recipient may have income even if the recipient does not receive a Form 1099-MISC. See the Instructions to Form 1099-MISC and the General Instructions for Certain Information Returns for more information. For payments to non-U.S. persons, see Publication 515, Withholding of Tax on Nonresident Aliens and Foreign Entities.

Q-14: Are payments made using virtual currency subject to backup withholding?

A-14: Payments made using virtual currency are subject to backup withholding to the same extent as other payments made in property. Therefore, payors making reportable payments using virtual currency must solicit a taxpayer identification number (TIN) from the payee. The payor must backup withhold from the payment if a TIN is not obtained prior to payment or if the payor receives notification from the IRS that backup withholding is required. See Publication 1281, Backup Withholding for Missing and Incorrect Name/TINs, for more information.

Q-15: Are there IRS information reporting requirements for a person who settles payments made in virtual currency on behalf of merchants that accept virtual currency from their customers?

A-15: Yes, if certain requirements are met. In general, a third party that contracts with a substantial number of unrelated merchants to settle payments between the merchants and their customers is a third party settlement organization (TPSO). A TPSO is required to report payments made to a merchant on a Form 1099-K, Payment Card and Third Party Network Transactions, if, for the calendar year, both (1) the number of transactions settled for the merchant exceeds 200, and (2) the gross amount of payments made to the merchant exceeds $20,000. When completing Boxes 1, 3, and 5a-1 on the Form 1099-K, transactions where the TPSO settles payments made with virtual currency are aggregated with transactions where the TPSO settles payments made with real currency to determine the total amounts to be reported in those boxes. When determining whether the transactions are reportable, the value of the virtual currency is the fair market value of the virtual currency in U.S. dollars on the date of payment.

See The Third Party Information Reporting Center, http://www.irs.gov/Tax-Profession..., for more information on reporting transactions on Form 1099-K.

Q-16: Will taxpayers be subject to penalties for having treated a virtual currency transaction in a manner that is inconsistent with this notice prior to March 25, 2014?

A-16: Taxpayers may be subject to penalties for failure to comply with tax laws. For example, underpayments attributable to virtual currency transactions may be subject to penalties, such as accuracy-related penalties under section 6662. In addition, failure to timely or correctly report virtual currency transactions when required to do so may be subject to information reporting penalties under section 6721 and 6722. However, penalty relief may be available to taxpayers and persons required to file an information return who are able to establish that the underpayment or failure to properly file information returns is due to reasonable cause.

source: http://www.businessinsider.com/irs-bitcoin-is-property-not-currency-full-release-2014-3?op=1

Answer (score 3):

I think it works like stock profits or losses.  But consult your accountant.

Answer (score 2):

While treating income from buying and selling bitcoins as investment income (i.e. like stocks) would be nice, it's not what I would recommend.  The advantage would be that capital gains taxes are cheaper than standard income.  The downside is that if the IRS rules that bitcoins are a currency instead of an asset, then the taxes are higher and if that's how they rule I'm certain they'll be performing audits on everyone that treated them as assets instead.

It means a higher tax bill, but I plan to treat it as a foreign currency while doing my taxes this year.  After all, that's the plan for bitcoin, isn't it, to be taken seriously as real money?  And if the IRS classifies bitcoins as an asset, I can always file an amended return later to recoup the over payment.

Answer (score 0):

TaxHawk finally has cryptocurrency filing instructions for the 2018 tax year:

> Cryptocurrency
>
> Where you report the income from cryptocurrency depends on how you received it.
>
> **Wages:** Menu Path: *Income > Common Income > Wages (W-2)*
>
> **Investment:** Menu Path: *Income > Common Income > Stocks or Investments Sold (1099-B)*
>
> **Mining:** Menu Path: *Income > Business Income > Business Income (Schedule C)*
>
> Virtual currency, also known as cryptocurrency or altcoin, is a medium of exchange that only exists digitally. It has no centralized authority but uses a decentralized system to record transactions and relies on cryptography to prevent counterfeiting and fraudulent transactions. Examples of cryptocurrencies are Bitcoin, Zcash, Litecoin, and Ethereum, just to name a few.
>
> Income paid in cryptocurrency or earned by buying, selling, or mining cryptocurrency is subject to taxation by the IRS. You can read the direction the IRS has given in [Bulletin 2014-21[image]](https://www.taxhawk.com/taxes2018/formdownload?form=IRS_bulletin-2014-21.pdf).
>
> Where you enter cryptocurrency income depends on how you earned the income. We'll give you an overview of the possible places below.
>
> Wages paid in cryptocurrency should be converted to U.S. dollars on the date of each payment by your employer and reported on your *Form W-2*. The conversion to dollars should have already happened before you get your *W-2*.
>
> Income paid to you in exchange for goods and services that wasn't wages (for example, you were paid for a service performed as part of your self-employed business in cryptocurrency) should be converted to U.S. dollars on the date of each payment and reported along with any other self-employment income.
>
> If you held cryptocurrency for investment, it should to be treated as a capital gain or loss.
>
> If you mined cryptocurrency, earnings from this activity should be converted to U.S. dollars as of the date you receive it and be included as income. If you were self-employed for the cryptocurrency mining, the income needs to be reported as self-employed income.