# in the united states if i buy or sell btc should i pay sales tax and captital gain tax?

Tags: taxes

As the title.suggests. I understand if I sell bitcoins, or make purchases (say I briefly sell for use then purchase good) I should pay capital gain if there was one. But should I also pay sales tax if I purchase btc for usd? Technically am I liable for sales tax?

Comment: Also if I purchase the currency on a exchange do they take care of it on their quarterly books (with fees and such)? I assume they do?

Comment: Regarding capital gains, see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/17351/how-to-file-bitcoin-income-to-the-irs.  I do not know about sales tax, but I have never heard of anyone charging or paying sales tax on a purchase or sale of bitcoins.